# Calculation of graduation grade in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have an error in my prolog program I try to calculate the CGPA in WinProlog and the code as follows:

```
grade(X).

start:-
    (   write('please enter ur cgpa'), read(X), X > 0 , X < 2,
        write('ur cgpa is poor'), write(X)
    ;   X >= 2, X < 3,  
        write('ur cgpa is good')
    ;   X >= 3, 
        write('ur cgpa is excellent')
    ).

 // comments

//  %cgpa(X,good):-grade(X) , X>=2 , X<3.

 // %cgpa(X,good):-grade(X) , X>=3 , write("your grade is excelent").

// is there anything missing, please help me
```

Comment: Can you describe the error? Try this: put a left paren `(` between `read(X),` and `X > 0`, and put a right paren `)` before the last period `.`. The commas have higher precedence than `;`.

Answer (score 3):

As @lurker noted, logical AND (`,`) and logical OR (`;`) are operators with different precedences. The expression doesn't necessarily bind the way you think it does. How does the expression

```
a , b ; c , d
```

bind? Is it...

- AND having higher precendence than OR: `(a,b) ; (c,d)`
- OR having higher precedence than AND: `a , (b;c) , d`
- Equal precedence, left-associative: `( ( (a,b) ; c ) , d )`
- Equal precedence, right-associative: `( a , ( b ; (c,d)))`

If you're not sure, make the binding clear with parentheses (but don't overdo it).

Further, one thing with Prolog is that alternatives are often better specified as individual clauses of a predicate rather than using the logical OR (`;`) operator. Something like this

```
evaluate_grade( X , poor      ) :- X >= 0.0 , X < 2.0 .
evaluate_grade( X , good      ) :- X >= 2.0 , X < 3.0 .
evaluate_grade( X , excellent ) :- X >= 3.0 .
```

is easier to debug, extend, modify and understand than your

```
( X>0 , X<2 ,
  write('ur cgpa is poor') , write(X) ;
  X>=2 , X<3,  
  write('ur cgpa is good') ; 
  X>=3 , 
  write('ur cgpa is excellent')
)
```

Taking this approach also helps lead you to the [*Single Responsibility Principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) — a fancy way of saying that things should do just one simple thing.

So, you might try *decomposing the problem* into smaller pieces that each do a single thing. Something like this:

```
start:-
  read_grade(X) ,
  evaluate_grade(X,R),
  write('Your CGPA is ') ,
  write(R) ,
  nl
  .

read_grade(X) :-
  write('please enter your CGPA: ') ,
  read(X),
  number(X)
  .

evaluate_grade( X , poor      ) :- X >= 0.0 , X < 2.0 .
evaluate_grade( X , good      ) :- X >= 2.0 , X < 3.0 .
evaluate_grade( X , excellent ) :- X >= 3.0 .
```

Comment: thanks for answer its fully answer the question but i have one more question ... when i run the program everything is ok but i have yes appear after the solution so can i ignore this yes or it is exist by default and i cannot remove? thanks

Comment: I don't know what Prolog implementation your using, but most Prolog interpreters, when evaluating a predicate at the interpreter prompt, indicate the success or failure of the evaluation by writing **`true.`**  or **`false.`** after the evaluation is complete. Backtracking (usually `;`) will find alternative solutions until the solution set is exhausted and the evaluation fails.